# Prevent "Migration executed but did not result in any SQL statements" message when running custom SQL in Doctrine migration

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am executing manual prepared statements in my Doctrine migration. I am doing this as I require the last inserted ID to build further related queries. Using the standard `addSql` method does not allow for this due to the nature of it "lining up" the queries and then executing them at the end.

Is there a way I can prevent the following error message from displaying?

`Migration 20151102112832 was executed but did not result in any SQL statements.`

There are many SQL statements executed, however they are execute when calling this method of mine:

```
/**
 * @param string $sql
 *
 * @throws DBALException
 */
private function runSql($sql)
{
    $this->write($sql);
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a "do nothing" sql:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->addSql('SELECT 1');
}
```

Comment: Good point :) Do you know if there's a way to display the output SQL in the same way as the `addSql` does? `write` just spits it out to the screen, but `addSql` prettifies it.

Comment: but what if we need prepare or executeQuery  to pass parameters?

Answer (score 5):

I think the best option here to show what your migration is doing.
You can do this and suppress warning message by sending sql request with comment string. For example:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    // Do not show warning on migrations.
    $this->addSql('# Updating entities.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

doctrine migration version 3 was throwing an error with MySQL5.7 when I used:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->addSql('SELECT 1');
}
```

Error Message:

```
[error] Migration DoctrineMigrations\Version20190823142208 failed during Post-Checks. Error: "An exception occurred while executing 'SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute."
```

This error can be fixed when using comments:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->addSql('#prevent warning' ); //Prevent “Migration executed but did not result in any SQL statements”
}
```